# limit of a product is the square root of -1?

Tags: limits

What is the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)+1+i}{k(k+1)+1-i}$$ where $i^2 = -1$?
My guess is that it is equal to $i$.

My idea to prove it was to set $k = \tan\theta_k$ to obtain an expression with $e^{i\theta}$ and transform the product into a sum and get rid of as many terms as possible. I was not able to get down to a result.

Does someone have a solution? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is: prove by induction on $n$ that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)+1+i}{k(k+1)+1-i} = i\;\frac{n+1-i}{n+1+i}
$$

Comment: How on Earth did you guess this formula?   Did you just work out a few terms, or is there some insight you had?